# BLANK Instruments screen when using 'Time Profiler'. Latest build of Xcode 6

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, instruments

A few days ago, 'time profiler' stopped working. Other instruments still work... core animation, allocations, etc. Time profiler is just a blank screen. No function calls showed, no graph, nothing. Same result for multiple projects.

I just reinstalled Xcode (over itself). Same problem. I can't find any preference files floating around that I can delete for Instruments. I really, really need this to work. I don't really have time to reinstall the entire OS.

[image]

## HELP

**Edit:** Deleting com.apple.dt.instruments.plist doesn't change anything. Found these logs in Console from instruments (below). Looks like something funny is going on, and probably worth submitting a bug to Apple. For now, the question is - how do I reset the state of instruments back to what it should be?

```
1/10/14 9:12:02.690 am Instruments[30211]: WebKit Threading Violation - initial use of WebKit from a secondary thread.
1/10/14 9:12:02.887 am Instruments[30211]: Invalid color System, labelColor (warning given only once)
1/10/14 9:12:04.761 am Instruments[30211]: <XRHorizontalFillSplitView: 0x6180001440a0>: the delegate <PFTTraceDocument: 0x7fda11423d90> was sent -splitView:resizeSubviewsWithOldSize: and left the subview frames in an inconsistent state:
1/10/14 9:12:04.761 am Instruments[30211]: Split view bounds: {{0, 0}, {1000, 629}}
1/10/14 9:12:04.761 am Instruments[30211]:     Subview frame: {{0, 0}, {1232, 247}}
1/10/14 9:12:04.761 am Instruments[30211]:     Subview frame: {{0, 248}, {1232, 323}}
1/10/14 9:12:04.761 am Instruments[30211]: The outer edges of the subview frames are supposed to line up with the split view's bounds' edges. NSSplitView is working around the problem, perhaps at the cost of more redrawing. (This message is only logged once per NSSplitView.)
1/10/14 9:12:04.762 am Instruments[30211]: <XRSplitView: 0x618000133240>: the delegate <PFTTraceDocument: 0x7fda11423d90> was sent -splitView:resizeSubviewsWithOldSize: and left the subview frames in an inconsistent state:
1/10/14 9:12:04.762 am Instruments[30211]: Split view bounds: {{0, 0}, {1000, 323}}
1/10/14 9:12:04.762 am Instruments[30211]:     Subview frame: {{0, 0}, {972, 223}}
1/10/14 9:12:04.762 am Instruments[30211]:     Subview frame: {{973, 0}, {259, 223}}
1/10/14 9:12:04.763 am Instruments[30211]: The outer edges of the subview frames are supposed to line up with the split view's bounds' edges. NSSplitView is working around the problem, perhaps at the cost of more redrawing. (This message is only logged once per NSSplitView.)
1/10/14 9:12:04.975 am Instruments[30211]: Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x61000009f810 h=-&- v=--& H:|-(22)-[NSSlider:0x6180001435a0]   (Names: '|':NSView:0x610000136760 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x61000009f7c0 h=-&- v=--& H:[NSSlider:0x6180001435a0]-(34)-|   (Names: '|':NSView:0x610000136760 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x61000009eeb0 h=-&- v=-&- H:|-(0)-[NSView:0x610000136760]   (Names: '|':NSClipView:0x7fda1164d0d0 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x61000009ee60 h=-&- v=-&- H:[NSView:0x610000136760]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':NSClipView:0x7fda1164d0d0 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x61000009ecd0 h=-&- v=-&- H:|-(0)-[NSClipView:0x7fda1164d0d0]   (Names: '|':NSScrollView:0x6180001db210 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x61000009ec80 h=-&- v=-&- H:[NSClipView:0x7fda1164d0d0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':NSScrollView:0x6180001db210 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x61000009e5f0 h=-&- v=--& H:|-(0)-[NSScrollView:0x6180001db210]   (Names: '|':PFTDataViewer:0x6100001edb00 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x61000009e5a0 h=-&- v=--& H:[NSScrollView:0x6180001db210]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':PFTDataViewer:0x6100001edb00 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x61000009dfb0 h=--& v=--& H:[PFTDataViewer:0x6100001edb00(0)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x61000009f7c0 h=-&- v=--& H:[NSSlider:0x6180001435a0]-(34)-|   (Names: '|':NSView:0x610000136760 )>

Set the NSUserDefault NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints to YES to have -[NSWindow visualizeConstraints:] automatically called when this happens.  And/or, break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Restarting the device solved the issue.

**Simulator > Hardware > Restart**